# How to set value of alphabet letter? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, letters, alphabet

Well, I have to make a task, that will sort elements of array in UNIQUE way.

So, for example, if I input 1st string:
BOB, I have to do: 2+15+2 (because of their positioning in the alphabet) and then divide by amount of chars /3 and do that for all inputted strings and then sort them by highest to lowest. :)

My question is, how do I set value 1,2,3,4,5... for A,B,C,D,E..... (only big letters).

Thank you.

Comment: he means he has homework to do, and doesn't want to do it...

Comment: This is not homework.

Comment: smells like it, considering it's an easy solve...

Comment: Well, considering I'm a beginner in C++, I wouldn't go and try to solve some complex and advanced challenges..

Comment: Hi @JohnSmith, as other comments have suggested, if this is homework please mark it as so with the [tag:homework] tag. Additionally, it's also recommended to post "what you've already got / tried". If you haven't got anything yet, maybe some pseudo code would be useful.

Comment: use a dictionary or map

Answer (score 2):

If the underlying encoding is seuqential, such as `ascii`.

```
letter - 'A' + 1
```

A more robust and general approach, would be to examine the [`char_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits) of the character type.

Comment: I don't think char_traits has what it takes for this.

Comment: What does the "letter" mean?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, I had [char_traits::to_int_type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/to_int_type) in mind.

Comment: @JohnSmith, `letter` is the letter you are are converting to a number, of course.

Comment: @StoryTeller that is basically an integral promotion. It "changes" char(0x41) to int(0x41).

Comment: So, let's say I have a code something like this:

 ` string b;
    cin >> b;
    int c;
    c = b - 'A' + 1; ` 
I get an error saying:
"no match for "operator-" in 'b - 'A'"

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, isn't that what the OP is after? (Yeah, they only want normalize the values, but why not make it safer?).

Comment: It's not safer. It does *nothing*. It does not change the value in any way. All it does is change types.

Comment: @JohnSmith, you get an error because a string is not a char, even if it's of length one.

Comment: Oh, what a dummy mistake, thank you for pointing that StoryTeller. I've got one more question. To split a string to chars, can I use [0] for first char? Also, what if I got an array of strings, how do I split the string to chars then?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, I know. I just don't like implicit casts.

Comment: @JohnSmith. Yes, that will get the first character. I suggest you take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/. It is a very good reference for any information about the standard containers you may come across.

Comment: I am learning C++98 right now, as I can see the website is related to C++11?

Comment: @JohnSmith, it is relevant to both. The things `C++11`-related are marked as such.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies. I'll ask you one last question. You've been through this and I would like to know, do you prefer to learn from eBooks or simply online by looking at articles & solving challenges? Which one is better?

Comment: I added a working example of "weight" function in my answer. Enjoy!

Comment: @JohnSmith, I prefer to learn along with a book, and than use Google when I do actual work. But considering how many poor books there are out there, I recommend you take a look at the book recommendation threads around [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a function

```
int weight(const std::string& s);
```

And then iterate on the string char by char and do following:

```
w = ch - 'A' + 1
```

You also may check that the char is before 'A' and 'Z' or assume that.

You need to read more about [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

**EDIT:**
Code of weight function (simplified):

```
int weight(const std::string& s) {
    int sum = 0, i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        char ch = s[i];
        sum += ch - 'A' + 1;
    }
    return sum/i;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "char"?

Comment: Sorry, fixed, I meant "ch", which is character. ch = s[i]; where i it's your loop counter.

Comment: Thank you. But will it work with a (std::string& s); ? One of the above answers said I must use a char. Even if the string is one letter, it won't work this way..

Comment: I added a working example of such function

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on an ASCII machine, @StoryTeller's answer works. Otherwise you can create an array to map between the two:

```
const char letters[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
static const int numbers [ 256 ] = { 0 };

for ( size_t index = 0; index < sizeof letters; ++index ) {
    numbers [ letters [ index ] ] = index + 1;
}

assert ( numbers [ 'A' ] == 1 )
assert ( numbers [ 'Z' ] == 26 )
```

Comment: What is an ASCII machine?

Comment: @JohnSmith a machine which uses ASCII for character representation, which is most machines now-a-days. Some mainframes used EBCDIC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC which has gaps, for example between I and J, so `'J' - 'I' != 1`

Answer (score 0):

To get the values you could use the following code:

```
int getValue(char which)
    {
    int ret = 0;
    switch(which)
       {
       case 'a' : ret = 1 ; break;
       case 'A' : ret = 27 ; break;
       case 'b' : ret = 2 ; break;
       case 'B' : ret = 28 ; break;
       // and so on....
       }
    return ret;
    }
  int result = 0;
  while(....)
     {
     result = result + getValue(myarray[counter]);
     }
```

You only need to escape the string to array and loop through it...

Comment: He asked only for big letters and you don't need to use such table, you may just using it's ASCII value (see answers below)

Comment: That's true... I don't need small chars, only big. And I was gonna use ASCII method except I wasn't sure how to do it.